# Show that $K_n*f \to f$ uniformly where $K_n$ is kind of a "mollifier"

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be bounded and uniformly continuous. $K_n \in L^1(R)$ has the following properties:
 $$\|K_n\|_1\leq M$$
$$\int_RK_n \to 1$$
$$\int_{|x|>\delta}|K_n|\to 0  (\delta >0)$$
I am to show that $K_n*f\to f$ uniformly.

Observation:
I am not sure if this is important but we know that for each $n$ $K_n*f$ is uniformly continuous as it is a convolution of an $L^1$ and $L^\infty$ function.

My attempt:

$$K_n*f(x)=\int_RK_n(t)f(x-t)dt$$
$$|K_n*f(x)-f(x)|\leq |K_n*f(x)+\int_RK_n(t)f(x)dt-\int_RK_n(t)f(x)dt-f(x)|\leq\int_R|K_n(t)||f(x-t)-f(x)|+|f(x)|    |\int_RK_n-1|$$
The second term can be made as small as we want (independently of $x$) as $f(x)$ is bounded and by property 2. There is a $\delta$ s.t if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$. Thus for the first term we split it up as follows:

$$\int_R|K_n(t)||f(x-t)-f(x)|=\int_{[-\delta,\delta]}|K_n(t)||f(x-t)-f(x)|+\int_{[-\delta,\delta]^C}|K_n(t)||f(x-t)-f(x)|$$Now the second term is again as small as we want as $f$ is bounded and by property 3. The first term can also is made as small as we by holders, and the fact that in our interval $[-\delta,\delta]$ the uniform continuity kick in.

Is this correct?

Comment: It seems correct. Only a few remarks. In your first inequality, you added and subtracted the same term. Therefore, it should be equality, not inequality. Also, I would introduce $\epsilon$ and say there exists $\delta$ such that for all $x,y$.... In your last line, I find it confusing. I'm guessing you mean to bound the first term by $M \epsilon$ since $|(x-t)-x|=|t|<\delta$. Overall though, nice proof.

Comment: @zugzug Correct that is what i meant, by holders applied on $K_n(t)\chi_{[-\delta,\delta]}|f(x-t)-f(x)|$ we get $M\epsilon$ as you say. Thank you!